# Get list of files paths

Tags: javascript, html

I didn't find an answer for this and I'm new to javascript. Anybody know if there is an equivalent in javascript for the "Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)" method from C#?

Comment: This is only possible if you plan to use a library outside of native javascript such as node js, app js, ajax, jquery/ajax, etc. Is this on a server or your local computer?

Comment: Hi Spencer, the files are on my local computer.

Comment: @cosmotel — Are you dealing in JavaScript embedded in an HTML page using `<script>`? The tags on your question imply that you are, but JavaScript has a broader range of applications than that.

Comment: @cosmotel — Assuming "yes" — are you talking about accessing the visitor's local file system or a subset of URLs on the website hosting the HTML document?

Comment: No just to create a .html page using the xml files and show some kind of summary after I read the files.

Comment: @cosmotel — "No"? No to what? No you aren't using JavaScript embedded in a `<script>`? What are you running the JavaScript in then? Windows Scripting Host? Node.JS? An Photoshop Extension? (The latter is, I admit, pretty unlikely).

Comment: No I don't want to host the html file for now, just to access my local files and prelucrate them..and yes I'm using the script tag. With jquery can I do this thing?

Comment: So you *are* using JS embedded in an HTML file with `<script>`. No. jQuery can't help. There is no way to get listings of local files from JavaScript embedded in an HTML document loaded over `file:` URIs.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do that with pure JavaScript, since it's a client side language (it works in your browser).

Comment: JavaScript works in many places that are not your browser (but since the question is also tagged HTML, its probably true in this instance). Extending this, it's worth mentioning that browsers (in the context of the WWW at least) don't work on directories, they deal in URLs.

Comment: True. I think he was asking whether he can access his local file system with JS, and that's not possible.

Comment: Yes that I was asking, if I could get my local files anf proces the xml files to create a .html page with  tables with some summary.

Comment: @cosmotel — You really need to clarify what you mean by "local", it is something people often misunderstand when talking about JavaScript and websites.

Comment: @cosmotel Let's say you had a website on a web server. With JavaScript, you could access the files that ARE on the server, but you couldn't access the files that are on user's machine.

Comment: Ok, I somehow understand why I can' t do this from  security perspective.. @Quentin by local I mean my hdd